# For $a>-1$, show that $\int_0^1x^a(1-x)^{-1}\ln(x)dx=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a+n)^{-2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

For $a>-1$, show that $\int_0^1x^a(1-x)^{-1}\ln(x)dx=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a+n)^{-2}$.

My trial was to write $(1-x)^{-1}$ and/or $\ln x$ by power series and taylor expansion, yet it did not work.

Any help are welcome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of replacing  $(1-x)^{-1}$ by its infinite Taylor expansion is good. Invert integration and summation. You then face integrands which are more or less $x^m$ $log(x)$ which can very easily be integrated by parts. This last point could be the one you missed.